# Deploy Qt3D project for Android under win 7

Tags: qt5

I've successfully deployed the cube example APK by creating a new Quick 2 project and copy qml file there, but got "module "Qt3D" plugin "qthreedqmlplugin" not found" error message, any clue for this? I already place the so file into imports/Qt3D folder, but no success. Thanks.

Edit: I tried using Qt 5.1.1 and followed the Qt3D installation described here (http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt3D-Installation) , and can get rid of the plugin not found error message above. But, this time, a message of “library “libQt53DQuick.so” not found” show up as follows:

W/Qt      (29930): assets:/qml/3dCube/main.qml:2 (): assets:/qml/3dCube/main.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "Qt3D": Cannot load library /data/data/org.qtproject.example.test3D/qml/Qt3D/libqthreedqmlplugin.so: (Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libQt53DQuick.so" needed by "libqthreedqmlplugin.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libQt53DQuick.so" not found)

Answer (score 2):

The problem been solved! After adding the following line in my .pro file:
  QT += qml quick 3dquick

The example works well in my sony android phone with adreno gpu, but not in my new lenovo yoga 8" with PowerVR gpu which I'll look into later.

Edit: BTW I eventually use QT5.2.1 for building my example.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.3 and the master branch of Qt3D as of today, all of the Quick3D demos work on my Note II (after pushing the qml files manually and changing onCompleted events to onStopped events).

Answer (score 0):

That's because in Qt 5.3 there was no way to figure out the plugin dependencies of qml imports. In 5.4, we have the qml import scanner that avoids the need to edit your .pro files to mention qml import dependencies.